# hibernate mapping класса без идентификатора

Tags: java, sql, xml, hibernate

есть класс Participant, они могут иметь идентификаторы в бд и маппятся как обычно
А есть два класса Employyes и Students, они внутри имеют только Set из Participant'ов

нужно промаппить их так, чтобы в бд появились таблицы EMPLYEES и STUDENTS, и содержали в себе только id'шники на своих членов. Заботиться о том, чтобы они не повторялись, буду уже сам. Пока пробовал так замкнуть таблицу саму на себе.

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="model.Employees" table="employees">
    <set cascade="save-update" name="employees" table="employees">
        <key column="par_id" not-null="true"/>
        <one-to-many class="model.Participant"/>
    </set>
</class>
```

1) как здесь отползти от того, что гибернейт требует завести первичный ключ для класса? у меня не будет много сущностей этих классов в бд, напротив 1 класс - 1 таблица, с 1 столбцом указывающим на участников в него входящих

2) нет ли подводных камней, чтобы потом обращаться к таким таблицам через критерию?
получится написать вот так?
(Employees) session.createCriteria(Employees.class).uniqueResult()

Comment: Может, пересмотреть классы и структуру таблиц? Какой смысл вы закладываете в один экземпляр класса Students?

Comment: Такое было условие к проекту, сама сущность "участника" не должна знать работник она или студент. Но должны быть перечисления "участники", "студенты" и "работники", при этом вот последние 2 как раз и знают своих участников.

Comment: вот поэтому мне и надо, чтобы была таблица "emloyees" и "students" и через них гибернейт сразу добирался до класса участника с уже кучей полей персональных данных. а как отползти от того, что к классам "emloyees" и "students" гибернейт требует создать к ним ke не знаю.

Comment: Мне кажется, вы слишком буквально поняли требование "должны быть перечисления". Перечисления не должны быть прямо в БД, имхо.

Если нужно обязательно отделить признак участия от сущности Участник, то можно было создать сущность Признак, которая по связи один-к-одному была бы соединена с Участником.

Set осмысленно использовать, например, для такой связи: Группа_студентов <-> Студент.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понимаю здесь классический случай `ORM mismatch`, при наследовании.
В *java* есть суперкласс **Participant** и его наследники **Employers** и **Students**.

Что значит

> есть два класса Employyes и Students, они внутри имеют только Set из
>   Participant'ов

непонятно.

Наверное, для каждой записи **Participant** есть одна запись в **Employers** или **Students**. И кроме того, у каждого из этих двух классов есть свои поля. Например, у **Employers** есть зарплата, а **Students** - стипендия.
Данная структура может мапиться на БД тремя стратегиями (в **JPA**, а в **HIBERNATE** четырьмя).
Для данного описанного случая подходит стратегия **JOINED** (с тремя таблицами в БД).

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Participant {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = Constants.ID_GENERATOR)
  protected Long id;
  @NotNull
  protected String firstName;
  // ...
}  

@Entity
public class Employers extends Participant {
  @NotNull
  long String salary;
  // ...
}
```

Подробно об этом можно прочитать в книге *Java Persistence with Hibernate
SECOND EDITION. CHRISTIAN BAUER, GAVIN KING, GARY GREGORY*, в главе *6.4 Table per subclass with joins.*

Также можно прочитать в спецификации *JPA 2.1, в главе 2.12.2 Joined Subclass Strategy.*

Или можно послушать лекцию на [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fKO6kbTUEuo) (в конце лекции)

Answer (score 0):

Решено, помог composite-id

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="model.Students" table="students">
    <composite-id name = "id" class = "model.Participant">
        <key-property name = "id" column="id" type = "integer"/>
        <key-property name = "firstName" type="string"/>
        <key-property name = "lastName" type="string"/>
        <key-property name = "patronymic" type="string"/>
    </composite-id>
</class>
```

класс выглядит как

```
public class Participant implements Serializable{
private Integer id;
private String lastName;
private String firstName;
private String patronymic;
...}
```

а вот его класс-обёртка указывающая на принадлежность к работникам

```
public class Employees implements Serializable {

private Participant id;
...}
```

выдирать из бд можно с обёрткой и без

```
List<Employees> e = (List<Employees>) session.createCriteria(Employees.class).list();
```

На выходе будет `[Employees{id=Participant{id=num, lastName=data, firstName=data, patronymic=data}},...]`

```
List<Participant> p = (List<Participant>) session.createCriteria(Employees.class)
                    .setProjection(Projections.property("id"))
                    .list();
```

И выплюнется `[Participant{id=num, lastName=data, firstName=data, patronymic=data},...]`

Comment: Какая получается схема БД, нет ли в таком варианте дублирования данных в БД?

Comment: Да вы правы, дублирование действительно происходит.
<key-property> отвечает за то, какие поля от участника причислять к работникам/студентам. чего не перечислил, того запросы критерии и не найдут.
Попробую через один к одному, но то мне кажется тоже не слишком удачным
ведь по идее будет таблица "студенты", а в ней

| id студента | id участника |

но индексировать самих студентов, то мне не надо, все участники и так разные

Comment: Таблица должна быть не _Студенты_, а _Роль_: |id участника|роль участника|

По такой таблице легко получить всех студентов, работников и т.п.

Роль - это "студент", "сотрудник", "работник". Если участник не может иметь сразу несколько ролей, то связь один-к-одному.